# Is it possible to use Boto with Django?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm really unfamiliar in this area. Is it possible to access the AWS API from Django? E.g. by using Boto? Can that be run on Django?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

There is even a django app for using boto. It is called [django-boto](https://github.com/qnub/django-boto).

It is the first result when you [search for "django boto"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=django%20boto).

Answer (score 1):

Sure. `boto` is just python library and you can use it from Django.

I used `boto` from other web frameworks (CherryPy, Flask), and it simply works. There is no reason it would not work with Django.